# What do the values of θ, ɸ, and λ represent visually in the Bloch Sphere when defining a unitary gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, bloch-sphere

In [IBM Quantum Docs](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/admin/docs/admin/guide/advanced-single-qubit-gates), it is stated that a unitary matrix can be defined as

$U = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta/2) & -e^{j\lambda}\sin(\theta/2) \\ e^{j\phi}\sin(\theta/2) & e^{j\lambda+j\phi}\cos(\theta/2)\end{bmatrix}$

In the case of a qubit, the values of $\theta, \phi, \&\ \lambda$ represent an angle on the x axis, z axis, and a phase shift. Is there any analog to this when defining a gate as a unitary matrix using these same parameters, and if so, how can it be visualized?

Comment: see https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2513/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16533/55

Comment: Thank you. Trishant's comment in the first link was what I was looking for. I am not familiar with the rules of this site. Should I leave the post up or take it down because it is somewhat of a duplicate?

Comment: These are called as Euler Angles by the way.

Comment: @SatvikDuddukuru no need to delete the question, I'll just close it as duplicate of that one